# How do I transfer a list from between two Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I transfer a list from Form1 to Form2?

I am getting an error on `Form2 showme = new Form2(Freezers);`.

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<macivari> Freezers = new List<macivari>();

        Freezers.Add(new macivari
        {
            Names="Toshiba",

            Id=1,
            about=new macivariabout
            {
                Doors="2",
                Celsius=-30
            }
            });

        Freezers.Add(new macivari
        {
            Names = "Samsung",
            Id = 2,
            about = new macivariabout 
            {
                Doors="1",
                Celsius=-60
            }
        });

        foreach (var item in Freezers)
            {
                if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "მაცივარი")
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item.Names);
                }
                else
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
                }

            }

        Form2 showme = new Form2(Freezers);
        showme.ShowDialog ();
    }
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public List<string> Freezers=new List<string>();
    public Form2(List<string> a)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Freezers = a;
        foreach (var item2 in Freezers)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: For starters, your `Form 2` constructor takes in an argument of `List<string>` but you're passing in `List<macivari>` to it

Comment: `zakaria` here is an awesome site I would suggest you start reading and learning how to work with the C# Language [C# Basics For Beginners](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're passing is:

```
List<macivari>
```

The type the constructor expects is:

```
List<string>
```

These are not the same type.

If `Form2` needs a `List<macivari>`, then it should expect one:

```
public List<macivari> Freezers=new List<macivari>();
public Form2(List<macivari> a)
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Freezers = a;
    foreach (var item2 in Freezers)
    {

    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, it really does need a `List<string>` then you should supply it with one.  How should a `macivari` be represented as a `string`?  By its `Names` property, for example?  Something like this?:

```
Form2 showme = new Form2(Freezers.Select(f => f.Names).ToList());
```

Comment: here is Edited code of Form 1 (do you mean this?) there is no error anymore but i cant access items from Form 2

Comment: //Form2 showme = new Form2(string);
            //showme.ShowDialog ();
            Form2 showme = new Form2(Freezers.Select(f => f.Names).ToList());
            showme.Show();
        }

Comment: and his is what i have done in Get Set

Comment: @zakaria: What do you mean by "can't access items from Form 2"?  What are you trying to do and how is it not working?  Keep in mind that with the code you just posted in your comment you are not providing Form 2 with the *actual items*, you're only providing it with the *names* of those items.  If you need to pass it the list of actual items, then pass it that list.  If it only needs strings, then pass it only strings.  I can't know what you intend to do with these items in your application, that's up to you.

Comment: public class macivariabout
        {
            public string Doors { get; set; }
            public int Celsius { get; set; }
        }
        public class macivari
        {
            public string Names { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public macivariabout about { get; set; }
        }

Comment: For example in Form2 i need see beforehand written items (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @zakaria: I'm afraid the language barrier is proving to be difficult here. Understand that C# is a statically typed language. You can't use an object where a string is expected, for example. So if you need to supply a list of your custom objects to `Form2` then the types on `Form2` need to match what you have to send to it.  I can't really be any more clear about that.

Comment: mainly i needed to fix error so you did it thank you so much boys ;) it too much helpful for me